# Firefox not displaying Unicode characters after post method

Tags: html, post, unicode

I have a page http://nepalicalendar.rat32.com/index_nep.php. It displays the nepali unicode page correctly. But after i click the submit button named "View Calendar" Firefox displays unreadable unicode characters. However, other browser does not shows the same problem.

Is there any code i need to add so that Firefox will display unicode character after post method?

Help will be really appreciated if someone could figure out whats wrong going on!! Thanks in advance.

[Note: I have added utf-8 code for displaying the nepali unicode character]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
The mistake i was doing was i had placed the tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

after favicon, title tags and meta description and title tags. After i placed tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

right after the head tag it worked fine. :)

**Conclusion: We should put the meta charset tag at the top, right after the head tag, before anything else, even the title tag.**

Cheers.. :)